# Apply Webgrid Pagination to a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

My question is simple. MVC3 has a Webgrid Helper which can be used for paging.
Is there a way to use this helper in a table instead of using the webgrid?

Please advise me in this.

Comment: You can use the `webgrid` in table but you cannot apply pagination of `Webgrid` to a table

Answer (score 0):

The Pager helper needs a WebGrid to work. If you do not want to use the WebGrid, you can create your own paging links. This article explains how, although it is based on the Web Pages framework and shows how to use paragraphs instead of tables: [http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/150/Web-Pages-Efficient-Paging-Without-The-WebGrid](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/150/Web-Pages-Efficient-Paging-Without-The-WebGrid.)

However, if you want to display your results in a table, I don't know why you don't use the WebGrid. It renders a table.